# how can we control the products to be displayed under latest products in open cart

Tags: php, opencart

can we control the products that are displayed under latest section. I want to display only selected products under the latest products section in homepage.

Comment: what did you tried so far..?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can control it with its controller file: `catalog/controller/module/latest.php` or in it's template file located at: `catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/latest.tpl`
you also need to check if it's homepage or not:

```
<?php
  if (!isset($this->request->get['route']) || $this->request->get['route'] == 'common/home') {
    $isHome = true; 
    }else{
    $isHome = false;
    }
?>
```

Comment: I mean to say can we pick only selected products and display it under the newly added product.

Comment: yes, you can create an `array` of your selected product names or their Ids. then in `latest.tpl` inside `foreach` use `in_array` and select only your selected products to be shown.